# How to identify and locate maximum values in each individual row of a raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I am looking to identify and locate maximum values in each individual row of a raster. I have tried many different methods including edge detection (Sobel, Canny,   Prewitt, etc.), focal statistics and generating contours (ArcGIS). However, the magnitude of the maximum value vary considerably from row to row - so the lower value maximums are difficult to (visually) identify using the methods mentioned above (see sample image below).

[image: Sample Image]

Ideally I would like to start at the top row of the raster and identify the location of the maximum value in each row from top to bottom.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question/Best answer" model operates. This question is likely *too broad* to get answers, it's also somewhat *opinion-based* due to the secondary question. You might be best off trying to implement in what you believe to be the best solution, then returning here with a specific issue in your implementation (if you encounter one).

Comment: Secondary question deleted. Also deleted second GIS software tag. Thank you.

Comment: Is it a float or integer raster? What is your desired output?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly then I would suggest some form of image enhancement before you run an edge detection for example. Having said that if you use something like a high pass filter in ArcMap then you can play around with the weighting to make these stand out better.

Comment: Is it a float or integer raster? Float

Comment: What is your desired output? Reply: Coordinates of the cell with maximum value for each row. These will then be used to create a polyline.

Comment: You can identify the max value in any row using Python and Numpy.   Convert your raster to a numpy array. Use numpy.matrix.math to get the max value along the x axis.  You would need to iterate through each row of your numpy array and build a new array to convert back to an ESRI GRID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution below is using little known raster algebra function ROWMAP.

```
arcpy.gp.SingleOutputMapAlgebra_sa("$$ROWMAP", "c:/SCRATCH/rows", "")
arcpy.gp.ZonalStatistics_sa("rows", "VALUE", "depth", "C:/SCRATCH/MAX_DEPTH", "MAXIMUM", "DATA")
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa('Con("MAX_DEPTH" == "depth","depth")', "C:/SCRATCH/EXTRACT")
arcpy.RasterToPoint_conversion(in_raster="EXTRACT", out_point_features="C:/SCRATCH/POINTS.shp", raster_field="Value")
arcpy.PointsToLine_management(Input_Features="POINTS", Output_Feature_Class="C:/SCRATCH/TALVEG.shp", Line_Field="", Sort_Field="", Close_Line="NO_CLOSE")
```

To make it work make sure that you mxd environment extent, snap raster and cell size are pointing to raster of interest.

Be prepared for surprises, i.e. final line might need manual polish:

[image]

Comment: Rowmap? Now you are just showing off! 

Comment: Thanks for this FelixIP - this looks like a very interesting solution - I will try it out and let you know how it works for me. DM

Comment: FelixP: This solution worked absolutely perfectly - it is a very concise and elegant solution! Thank you very much - I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to create a polyline from the coordinates of the cell with the maximum value on each row why not:

1. Convert the raster to a point dataset.
2. Add XY values to the points.
3. Run summary tool getting max value by Y coordinate (as Y is constant over the row)
4. Join the Summary table back to your point dataset base upon Y field
5. Select where value = max value
6. Export your selection (optional)
7. Run points to line tool based upon Y field

Comment: Good one, but raster size could be an issue.

Comment: Many thanks for this - I look forward to trying it out.